# Avoid RDD nested in Spark without Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've a big problem!

I have an `RDD[(Int, Vector)]` , where the `Int` is a sort of label.

For example :

```
(0, (a,b,c) );
(0, (d,e,f) );
(1, (g,h,i) )
```

etc...

Now, i need to use this RDD(I call it myrdd ) like this :

```
myrdd.map{  case(l,v) => 
   myrdd.map { case(l_, v_) => 
      compare(v, v_)
   }
}
```

Now, I know that it's impossible in spark to use RDD nested.

I can bypass the problem using an Array. But for my problem i can't use Array, or anything that goes in memory.

How could I resolve my problem WITHOUT USING ARRAY?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

`cartesian` sounds like it should work:

```
myrdd.cartesian(myrdd).map{
  case ((_,v),(_,v_)) => compare(v,v_)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It means that if my rdd has N elements, the cartesian product will give me an rdd of N*N elements, right?